# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server

Getting this strange issue,

I have a user defined table:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Crates_FruitsType] AS TABLE 
(
    [FruitID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CrateID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And a stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Crates_InsertRelateMultipleFruits]
    (@FruitCrates As Crates_FruitsType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE rc
    FROM Crates_Fruits rc
    WHERE rc.CrateID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tmp.CrateID 
                         FROM @FruitCrates tmp);

    INSERT INTO Crates_Fruits (FruitID, CrateID)
       SELECT 
          tmp.FruitID, tmp.CrateID
       FROM 
          @FruitCrates tmp
       WHERE 
          tmp.FruitID <> '-1';
END
```

And table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Crates_Fruits]
(
    [EchoID] [int] NULL,
    [FruitID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CrateID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Crates_Fruits] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Crates_CrateID] 
  FOREIGN KEY([CrateID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Crates] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Crates_Fruits] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Crates_CrateID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Crates_Fruits] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruits_FruitID2] 
  FOREIGN KEY([FruitID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Fruits] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Crates_Fruits] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruits_FruitID2]
GO
```

And this C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    connection.Open();

    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT.Columns.Add("FruitID", typeof(int));
    DT.Columns.Add("CrateID", typeof(int));

    if (fruitIDs.Count < 1)
       DT.Rows.Add(crateID, -1);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fruitIDs.Count; i++)
            DT.Rows.Add(fruitIDs[i], crateID);
    }

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Crates_InsertRelateMultipleFruits", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var testingparam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FruitCrates", DT);
        testingparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Crates_CrateID". The
>   conflict occurred in database "FruitFactory", table "dbo.Crates",
>   column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

It works perfectly but gives error when I pass data as

```
CrateID = 172
FruitID = -1
```

I am expecting stored procedure to,

if FruitID is passed as "-1" then only delete all records where CrateID is 172
Otherwise delete all records where CrateID is 172 and add new datatable

Comment: The error says you tried to insert a value that doesn't exist in the parent table. Do the IDs exist in the parent tables?

Comment: Obviously, you're trying to insert a row with `CrateID=172` into `Crates_Fruits`, while that values doesn't exist in the `Crates` table (as column `ID`). Fix that and the error will go away ..... (btw: that's the **whole point** of a foreign key - preventing inserts of data that doesn't make sense!)

Comment: You are comparing an int (FruitID) to a string `'-1'`. I don't think this is the problem but you are forcing an unnecessary conversion. Does the value `172` exist? Have you tried calling the stored procedure directly? Does it work with the values (172,-1) ?

Comment: It's not a *strange issue* - it's the way a foreign key is **supposed to work** :-)

Comment: You reversed the column order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reversed the order of the columns. Your type is defined as `(FruitId,CrateId)` but your C# code enters the `crateID` first when there are no fruit IDs:

```
if (fruitIDs.Count < 1)
   DT.Rows.Add(crateID, -1);
```

It should be

```
if (fruitIDs.Count < 1)
   DT.Rows.Add(-1,crate);
```

To execute your stored procedure directly, just create a variable using the table type and insert the values you want, eg:

```
declare @t [Crates_FruitsType]
insert into @t VALUES(-1,172)
exec [Crates_InsertRelateMultipleFruits] @t
```